# Counting number of times a character is inputted

Tags: java, string, char

I am trying to have my code output the exact number of times a certain character is said in an inputted sentence (For example e).

I tried using a char and for statement so its able to count but it gives me the wrong value

```
int countChar;
char e = '\0';
String str;
int count = 0;
System.out.println("input your sentence:");
str = in.next();

    for(i=0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {    if(str.charAt(i) == e)
            count++;
    }

    System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner doesn't read whole sentence - difference between next() and nextLine() of scanner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058912/scanner-doesnt-read-whole-sentence-difference-between-next-and-nextline-o)

Comment: Why are you counting the occurrences of the nul character?

Comment: what would i change for it to look for the e or E character in a sentence

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `if(str.charAt(i) == e)` to `if(str.charAt(i).equals("e"))`, you don't really require a variable for this. You just require the quotation marks, and since you are comparing a string, you should use the above `String.equals()` method.

If you are looking for uppercase letters as well, use the `||` (OR) operator and do the same but replace the lowercase e with an uppercase

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'e' instead of '\0' when comparing the characters